# Realm: Get objects with selection on list properties

Tags: ios, swift, realm

My Model Classes (shortened):

```
class Customer: RealmSwift.Object {
  let orders = List<Order>()
}

class Order: RealmSwift.Object {
  @objc dynamic var areaCode: String? = nil
  @objc dynamic var isPaid: Bool = false
}
```

Now I want to get all Customers with non paid orders in a given area.

I use this query to get them (I tested this query using Realm Studio):

```
orders.areaCode == '5429' and orders.isPaid == false
```

But with this Query I don't get only customers with non paid orders in '5429'.
I also get customers with orders in '5429' and paid orders in another area.
But I get only customers with both parts, but even in different rows.

How can I change my query to get only "customers with non paid orders in '5429'"?

Comment: I think you can do that with a subquery. But I'm not sure because you actually can't do this in realm-java (yet) unless you do `where().findAll().where().findAll()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to find all `Customer`s whose `orders` property contains at least one `Order`, where the `areaCode` is "5429" and `isPaid` is `false`.

```
let areaCode = "5429"
let nonPaidInArea = realm.objects(Customer.self).filter("SUBQUERY(orders, $order, $order.areaCode == %@ AND $order.isPaid == false).@count>0",areaCode)
```